# Sonatype Nexus problems downloading jars

Tags: maven, build, repository, nexus, dynamic-jasper

I am trying to configure SonaType Nexus OSS for my application which currently when builds downloads the jars from the respective repositories on web. The 
structure of settings file is:

```
<settings>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
      <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
     <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

My Application was using Dynamic Jasper for which i had to explicitly mention the repository in the pom as:

```
<repository>
    <id>djmaven2</id>
    <url>http://nexus.fdvs.com.ar/content/groups/public/</url>
    <name>DynamicJasper public Repository</name>
</repository>
```

the respective dependency for the same was:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ar.com.fdvs</groupId>
    <artifactId>DynamicJasper</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Without mentioning -s settings.xml the build worked perfectly, but when I am passing the setting file I am getting this error:

```
[

ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project reports: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.ict:reports:jar:2.2.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js4, org.olap4j:olap4j:jar:0.9.7.309-JS-3, 
ar.com.fdvs:DynamicJasper:jar:5.0.0: Failure to find com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js4 in http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

I even uploaded the artifact manually to the Nexus sonatype Nexus' 3rd party repositories, but that did not help either.

Can anyone suggest where I could be going wrong with this?

Comment: If you configured the settings.xml file as describes adding supplemental repositories in the pom.xml will not work cause they will redirected to the configured nexus. If you need to have a supplemental repository you have to configure that in Nexus...

Comment: and how do i achieve that?

Comment: What about reading the documentation of Nexus http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/ ?

Comment: This is good information, so i added a proxy repository which points to the url of dynamic jasper, now i added this proxy repository to the default public group i am referring to in my settings.xml file, however the error still doesn't go :( even though the jars are visible on url http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/ i can not use the proxy repository url as it would then download all jars on a wrong repository under nexus, anything i could be missing?

Comment: Have you deleted the folder of those dependencies in your local cache and retry the build?

Comment: By local cache you mean the storage of nexus or my local .m2?

Comment: Ah sorry i mean your local repository `$HOME/.m2/repository`

Comment: "Failure to find com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js4 in http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced "  ... Maven has cached a previous download failure.  Run the build with "-U" to clear this flag.  Then you'll be able to see the real problem.